# Unable to install Ionic package built apk on Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) from Google Chrome

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have had a problem on Android Marshmallow (6.0) installing an apk from Google Chrome on the device. I have a Lollipop device (5~) that allows install, however the Marshmallow device just states "Cannot open file". I have no problem using Appgyver's supersonic package tool but with Ionic Package it won't allow me to install from an apk.

I've done some research and found that by using an alternative browser on the device such as firefox or by using a third party file manager I am able to install the apk. The article below suggests Google Chrome is now locking out app installs not on the play store but I'm doubtful of this theory due to being able to install other apk's ok.

[Frostwire Article for workaround](http://support.frostwire.com/hc/en-us/articles/204106249-How-to-fix-Can-t-Open-File-error-while-installing-FrostWire-Plus-on-Android-)

This has been a common workaround used by other reports of a similar issue online and does work for my case. Unfortunately this is an effort required by the customer that is damaging to the ease of access to the application.

It seems to be an issue exclusive to Android 6.0 (not exclusively Ionic package built apk's). This being said as I am able to build an apk and install from Chrome using Appgyvers 'Supersonic' services using the same device so I'm lead to believe there is indeed a solution to the problem.

Be aware that I am using Ionic package to build a "release" version and customers cannot have "developer mode" turned on. As well as this I have "allow untrusted sources option" engaged.

Does anyone have any insight on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered the problem. It appears firefox and older versions of Chrome are far less picky with Content-Type headers on file downloads for apk's. The App was being downloaded with the content-type head of  `application/octet-stream`. Firefox (Android 6) and Chrome (Android 5.1) took no notice of this when trying to figure out the file type and were happy enough installing.

However Chrome on Android 6.0 requires a content type of `application/vnd.android.package-archive` for it to discern the type of file it has downloaded.

Anyway I made that change on the download and it now works!